# In Org-Mode, how to export to ASCII, maintaining capitalisation of the heading

Tags: org-mode, org-export

Whenever I export to ASCII, the heading always converts to all capitals. How can I maintain the original capitalisation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`upcase` is hard-coded into `org-ascii-template--document-title` of Org-version 9.2.6.
The following Elisp code neutralizes that `upcase` by temporarily setting `upcase` to `identity`.

Note that one of the preconditions of the advice is that the source code of `ox-ascii` is available to Emacs. That is the case if you have installed the Melpa version of Org or you have installed the Elisp source package for Emacs. Under Ubuntu the Emacs Elisp source package is `emacs26-el`.

```el
^;; -*- lexical-binding:t -*-
;; Lexical binding can become relevant for generalized variables
;; (see doc string of `gv-ref').

(require 'cl-lib)

(defcustom org+-ascii-upcase-title nil
  "Default value for :"
  :type 'boolean
  :group 'org-export-ascii)

(eval-after-load 'ox-ascii
  '(eval ;; Avoid expansion of `cl-pushnew' for place `org-export-backend-options' before ox-ascii is loaded.
    '(cl-pushnew (list :ascii-upcase-title nil "ascii-upcase-title" 'org+-ascii-upcase-title)
         (org-export-backend-options (org-export-get-backend 'ascii))
         :test #'equal :key #'car)))

(defun org+-ascii-ignore-upcase (fun info)
  "Neutralize `upcase' if :ascii-upcase-title is not set when calling FUN with INFO."
  (if (assoc-string (plist-get info :ascii-upcase-title) '(yes t on))
      (funcall fun info)
    (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'upcase) #'identity))
      (funcall fun info))))

(advice-add 'org-ascii-template--document-title :around #'org+-ascii-ignore-upcase)
```

You can switch on upcasing the title by the following option in your org file:

```org
#+OPTIONS: ascii-upcase-title:t
```

Instead of `t` also the values `on` and `yes` work. Any other value such as `no` switches upcasing off.
You can customize the default with the Elisp variable `org+-ascii-upcase-title`.

Tested with Emacs 26.3 and Org 9.2.6.

Comment: This gives me the error - let*: Symbol’s function definition is void: \(setf\ org-export-backend-options\). I am on version 9.1.9 if that's the issue?

Comment: @randouser I have fixed the bug. Nevertheless, I am not sure why the original version did not work. I will post a question about that later this night.

Comment: I no longer get the error, but when I export as ascii, the title is still capitalised. On emacs 26.3.

Comment: @randouser I noticed that the org library is not byte-compiled in my setup. It turns out that the symbol `upcase` is not directly contained in the byte-compiled code but only some reference to the underlying function. So the advice remains without effect for the byte-compiled code. I now enforce the loading of the source of `ox-ascii`. This should work for you if you have the sources for that package installed on your system.

Comment: @randouser I have corrected the code after the cause of the problem has been clarified in [the answer to my question about `with-eval-after-load` and `pushnew`](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/55903/2370).

Comment: And it works now! That's great, thanks for your persistence.